# Spring boot application hot reload with text editors

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, hot-reload

How to develop spring boot application with pure text editors?

And with hot reload after you save your source code file. With build tools like maven or gradle.

Comment: You should use an IDE cause Spring boot is Java Code...In Spring Boot..you can add the spring-boot-devtools which support hot reloading during development.

Comment: hmmm, sometimes just want to do in text editor.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out you could install spring-boot-devtools to your pom.xml before start.

Start your application with command line
$ mvn spring-boot:run

As long as your text-editor support auto compile, it will reload.

I am using vs code in this case. A java compiler will popup for installation while you edit your source code. Amazing.